# I am getting different answer by doing the same calculation in different ways ( which are almost similar ) in GNU C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, integer-overflow

I was basically trying to find the number obtained on multiplying 2 with the quotient obtained on dividing 5e+8 with 3. I tried a couple of ways as shown in the snippet with GNU C++17 and got the correct answer only in the Approaches 2 and 4. I was first expecting it to be some sort of overflow situation however the maximum number that a signed int can store is a little more than 2e+9 which is much greater than the numbers which I was dealing with so I think that the issue might be something else. It would be great if someone could help out. Thanks in advance : )

```
using namespace std;

int main(){

// I basically wan't to calculate: 2 * 500000000/3 ( 2 * 5e+8 / 3)

    // Approach 1
    cout<<2 * 500000000 / 3<<"\n";  // output : 333333333 (nine 3s) WRONG!

    // Approach 2
    int a = 500000000/3;    // output : 333333332 (eight 3s) CORRECT!
    cout<<2 * a<<"\n";

    // Approach 3
    a = 2 * 500000000/3;    // output : 333333333 (nine 3s) WRONG!
    cout<<a<<"\n";

    // Approach 4 
    cout<<500000000 / 3 * 2<<"\n";  // output : 333333332 (eight 3s) CORRECT!
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile for me unless I add `#include<iostream>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out.  I had to put a bracket for the 500000000 / 3 in Approach 1 and 3 as that was what I wanted to find out.  There is nothing wrong in what the output is. It was just a bad semantic error! Thank  you very much for helping me!

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the tick mark on the left-hand side of it.

Comment: Side note: I don't think "GNU C++17" is something that actually exists ;-) (Assuming you meant GCC + C++17 ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can verify that both the answers are in fact correct my hand.

(2*500,000,000)/3 = (1000,000,000)/3=333,333,333

and

(500,000,000/3)*2 = (166,666,666)*2 =333,333,332

This has to do with how in C++ integer division always rounds down and nothing to do with overflow. Arguably 333,333,333 is more accurate approximation of the "real" answer 333,333,333.333...

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations matters. When you calculate `2 * 500000000 / 3`, it's equal to

```
floor(floor(2 * 500000000)/3)
```

(in the mathematical meaning of operations on real numbers), while the calculation of `2 * (500000000/3)`, which is your second approach, is equal to

```
floor(2 * floor(500000000/3)).
```

This is because each integer arithmetic operation is *always* followed by rounding towards zero (which for non-negative result is the same as `floor`).

Approach 3 is equivalent to 1, and approach 4 is equivalent to 2.